# Misconception about counting number of sample points

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have recently been interested in studying probability, and so I have been reading through "Mathematical Statistics with Applications" by Wackerly, Mendenhall, Scheaffer (7th edition).

I need clarification on how to solve an example from this textbook. Here is the example:

> A company orders supplies from $M$ distributors and wishes to place $n$ orders ($n < M$). Assume that the company places the orders in a manner that allows every distributor an equal chance of obtaining any one order and there is no restriction on the number of orders that can be placed with any distributor. Find the probability that a particular distributor—say, distributor I—gets exactly $k$ orders ($k \leq n$).

The answer to this question is: $\frac{\binom{n}{k} (M-1)^{n-k}}{M^n}$.

I somewhat understand the rationale to the solution. This is my interpretation of the solution. When performing the initial counting process, we would have to count the number of ways to choose $k$ objects from $n$ total objects, which would be $\binom{n}{k}$. This represents the number of ways in which a particular vendor would hold $k$ orders. Once those $k$ orders have been distributed to that particular vendor, the remaining $n - k$ orders would then have to be distributed amongst $M-1$ vendors. There are $(M-1)^{n-k}$ ways to distribute $n-k$ orders to $M-1$ vendors, and so the number of sample points in the event that a particular distributor would obtain $k$ orders would then become $\binom{n}{k}(M-1)^{n-k}$. The total number of sample points to distribute $n$ orders would be $M^n$, and so we have the above solution because we compute the ratio of the number of sample points of the specified event over the total number of sample points.

**However, why couldn't we also account for the number of ways we would have choose a particular vendor to hold $k$ orders?** Any vendor has the potential of holding $k$ orders, and so we would have $M$ choices of vendors to pick from that would hold those orders.

Therefore, our final solution would become: $\frac{\binom{n}{k} (M) (M-1)^{n-k}}{M^n}$.

If there are any misconceptions about counting and loopholes in my reasoning, please correct me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the figure $\frac{{n \choose k}(M-1)^{n-k}}{M^n}$ is basically correct. This figure answers the question posed in the problem, which was concerning *one, pre-determined* supplier I.

However, what you seem to be trying to do later on (starting from your paragraph in **bold**) is: to answer a *different* question, which I presume is "Find the probability that *any* of the suppliers has exactly $k$ orders".

This would be a different, potentially a lot harder, question, with a different answer. For *that* question, your answer is incorrect, because it does not account for the possibility that *two or more* suppliers have exactly $k$ orders. (In other words, the events that each individual supplier has exactly $k$ orders are not mutually exclusive, so the law of adding probabilities does not hold.) Incidentally, if $k>\frac{n}{2}$, two suppliers cannot at the same time both have $k$ orders, so in *that* case your formula would be correct.

Comment: I was confused by the wording of the question which lead me to my formula, and so I appreciate your clarification. However, would my formula not account for the event that two or more suppliers have exactly $k$ orders? If $k < \frac{n}{2}$ and $k$ orders have already been given a distributor, then there would be $n - k$ orders left to distribute. When counting the number of ways the next $n - k$ orders can be distributed to $M - 1$ distributors, we would then need $(M-1)^{n-k}$ sample points. However the set of sample points include possibilities of multiple distributors holding $k$ orders?

Comment: If more than one distributor can have $k$ orders, then events that one (say $I_1$) has $k$ orders, and the other one (say $I_2$) has $k$ orders, are not disjoint (mutually exclusive). In effect you would've counted them *twice* in your calculation. A more complicated formula applies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Oh gotcha, I see what you mean now. Thank you very much. And happy new year! :D lol

Answer (score 0):

You can include the choice of the vendor to look at in your probability, but then you also have to include it in your sample space.

Your sample space then has $M^{n+1}$ members: $M^n$ for the distribution of orders, and an additional factor $M$ for your choice of the vendor to look at.

Now it is easy to see that this additional factor $M$ in the denominator exactly cancels out the additional factor $M$ in the numerator you correctly determined.

This means that it doesn't matter whether you choose you vendor randomly (the corrected second solution) or just look at a specific pre-selected vendor (your first solution). Which is to be expected because by construction, each vendor has an equal chance to get each order.

Comment: Hey celtschk, thank you for your response. I'm not sure if I quite understand, how would I include the choice of the vendor to look at in my sample space? Not sure how to describe this new sample space.

Comment: @phillip1618: Your sample space in that case consists of (a) all possible choices of a vendor to check, and (b) all possible distributions of orders. You have to include (a) because in that case it is also a random choice; it's the same reason you'd include it in the count on the numerator. Counting it in the number of ways leaving to $k$ orders for the chosen supplier but not counting it in the total number of ways would be inconsistent.